# Check if the value of object.property is value1 or value2

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I look for a solution to check if the value of the `labelKey` property is `to_be_rented` or `to_be_put_on_sale`

With a condition we can do it with :

```
if (this.project.currentProduct.productStatus.labelKey === ('to_be_rented' || 'to_be_put_on_sale')) {

}
```

But it does not work, and I also look for a more sophisticated alternative using Lodash or es2015 for example.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition works so:

1. The result of the expression `to_be_rented` || `to_be_put_on_sale` is `to_be_rented` always.
2. You compare that `labelKey` equals to `to_be_rented`.

The correct solution is to compare `labelKey` with both strings:

```
let labelKey = this.project.currentProduct.productStatus.labelKey;
if (labelKey === 'to_be_rented' || labelKey === 'to_be_put_on_sale')) {
   ...
}
```

With ES2016 it can be simplified:

```
let values = ['to_be_rented', 'to_be_put_on_sale'];
if (values.includes(this.project.currentProduct.productStatus.labelKey)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put all your variants in an array and use [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (it's even in ES5):

```
const variants = ['to_be_rented', 'to_be_put_on_sale'];
const labelKey = this.project.currentProduct.productStatus.labelKey;
if (variants.indexOf(labelKey) !== -1) {
  ...
}
```

Or [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (it's in ES2016):

```
if (variants.includes(labelKey)) {
  ...
}
```

These ways are more convenient when you have more than 2 variants.

For your case `Array.prototype.indexOf()` and `Array.prototype.includes()` will be the same, but the difference between these functions you can check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370222/array-prototype-includes-vs-array-prototype-indexof).

Comment: Or use `['...', '...'].includes(str)` with ES2016.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for a check if the value exist in the array.

```
const values = ['to_be_rented', 'to_be_put_on_sale'];
if (values.includes(this.project.currentProduct.productStatus.labelKey)) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lodash way:

```
var toFind = this.project.currentProduct.productStatus.labelKey;
if(_.find(['to_be_rented', 'to_be_put_on_sale'], toFind)) {
  // do something
}
```