# Is indexOf slower than trying to index an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't know much at all about performance. But, if `someArray.includes(someString)` has to search the whole array, would trying to find an index of an object be more direct (and thus faster, and also a bit less code)?

```js
// create an array of number strings
const arr = Array(100).from(n => n.toString());

// find whether a string is in the array
const isStringInArr_includes_true = arr.includes("50"); // true
const isStringInArr_includes_false = arr.includes("500"); // true

// instead of creating an array, create an object with the array items as keys
// EDIT: actually you can just use the array itself
// and look up the string as a key
const isStringInArr_lookup_true = !!arr["50"]; // !!("50") === true
const isStringInArr_lookup_false = !!arr["500"]; // !!(undefined) === false
```

Obviously this would only work with an array of strings.

Comment: `arr.push("500");` - And now?

Comment: Be careful, `arr["50"]` returns the value stored at the `"50"` index, not the index of the value `"50"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47660334/1823841

Comment: @palaѕн I am afraid this answer might be deprecated as the JS engines have evolved since 2017 and the perfs are close to being the same.