# How to filter an array based on another array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been struggling with this easy change. I basically have two arrays:

`let apps = [{name: "Insights", id: "INS"}, {name: "Recruit", id: "REC"}];`

`let securityApps = ["bw", "INS"];`

I am basically trying to filter down `apps` based on the elements inside `securityApps`

The result I am wanting to achieve is:
`[{name: "Insights", id: "INS"}];` (since `INS` is what they have in common in terms of ID) but still pass in `apps` variable

Here is what I have started:

```
apps.filter((app) => {
        securityApps.forEach((sgApp) => {
          if (app.id === sgApp){
            return app;
          }
        })
      });
```

`apps` is later implemented as

```
apps.map(...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way, using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
let apps = [{
  name: "Insights",
  id: "INS"
}, {
  name: "Recruit",
  id: "REC"
}];

let securityApps = ["bw", "INS"];

const filtered = apps.filter(app => securityApps.indexOf(app.id) > -1)

console.log(filtered)

const filtered2 = apps.filter(app => securityApps.includes(app.id))

console.log(filtered2)
```

<s>Using `indexOf` would be better as `includes` won't work in [Internet Explorer](https://caniuse.com/?search=includes) without polyfills. And perhaps `indexOf` is faster on chrome as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47660334/2873538).</s>

Comment: Thanks for sharing the compatibility issue @Ajeet

Comment: it's ok no problem

Comment: @ZiaurRehman I think using `includes` is cleaner and shorter. And Internet Explorer [usage share is extremely low](https://gs.statcounter.com/). And which one is faster will keep changing and nobody cares. `includes` is short and clean as your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66714101/2873538) suggests. +1

Comment: Thank you @AjeetShah!

Answer (score 2):

Really simple answer

```
const newArray = apps.filter(app => securityApps.includes(app.id)))
```