# Is there a better way to write || in a single if statment

Tags: javascript

was wondering if there is a better way to write the code below. I want my if statement to ignore all of the keycodes. but seems quite a messy way to write it as below.

thanks!

```
if (event.keyCode === 9 
   || event.keyCode === 91 
   || event.keyCode === 20 
   || event.keyCode === 18 
   || event.keyCode === 17 
   || event.keyCode === 37)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
if ([9, 91, 20, 18, 17, 37].includes(event.keyCode))
```

Comment: In terms of performance, I would highly recommend you should use `indexOf` instead  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659972/array-indexof-vs-includes-perfomance-depending-on-browser-and-needle-positio  @blex

Comment: @NguyễnVănPhong you're overthinking ;) Yes, it might make sense if you have thousands of values that you have to check a thousand times. We're talking about key strokes here. `includes` exists for a reason: to make your code easier to understand

Comment: @blex Yeah. It's just another aspect of computer science - `performance, time/space complexity, etc..`. And yes, `includes` work as well :)

Answer (score 5):

For a larger list of values that you compare with often, it may be more optimal to use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```
const codes = new Set([9, 91, 20, 18, 17, 37]);
if(codes.has(event.keyCode)){
   // do something
}
```

Comment: In case anyone doesn't know why it will be more optimal `has` is an O(1) operation while `includes` is O(n), since Sets have an O(1) search time, while Arrays have an O(n) search time.
The speed improvement may not be that evident for a small number of elements like in this case, but it is good practice regardless and according to this post even at 10 elements `has` is slightly faster: https://dev.to/arnaud/using-array-prototype-includes-vs-set-prototype-has-to-filter-arrays-41fg

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead.

```
if ([9, 91, 20, 18, 17, 37].some(val => val === event.keyCode))
```

or

```
if ([9, 91, 20, 18, 17, 37].indexOf(event.keyCode) !== -1)
```

---

*In terms of performance*, I would highly recommend you should use `indexOf`.

- [Array indexOf() vs includes() perfomance depending on browser and needle position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659972/array-indexof-vs-includes-perfomance-depending-on-browser-and-needle-positio)

And another aspect you should take care of is between `includes` and `indexOf` in case of **`NAN`** issue. There are 2 posts below that can help you have comprehensive knowledge about them:

- [Array.prototype.includes vs. Array.prototype.indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370222/array-prototype-includes-vs-array-prototype-indexof)
- [Why does [NaN].includes(NaN) return true in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66743472/why-does-nan-includesnan-return-true-in-javascript)

Comment: `includes` is more performant than `some` or `indexOf`

Comment: I'm not sure :) @arieljuod

Comment: I've updated my answer with some docs related to performance, Pls kindly take a look at it @arieljuod

Comment: Keep in mind that those benchmarks results are from 2017, this benchmark shows a really big difference in performance for includes https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/6029/0/some-vs-filter-vs-indexof-vs-includes with the current Chrome version and only a slightly worst performance with the current firefox, but yes it depends on the browser (though with that difference for chrome I would still go with includes over indexOf)

Comment: Agree. It really depends on specific browser implementation. @arieljuod

Answer (score 3):

Like others have said, you can create an array or set with the valid key codes and test for membership using the event.keyCode variable. I wrote some example code below for how you could do this in a clean way :)

```
// let eventKeyCode = event.keyCode;
let eventKeyCode = 28;
let validKeyCodes = [9, 91, 20, 18, 17, 37];
if (validKeyCodes.includes(eventKeyCode)) {
  // do something 
  console.log(`event has valid key code: ${eventKeyCode}`);
} else {
  // catch logic
  console.log(`event has invalid key code: ${eventKeyCode}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the if logic into a function.

```js
function isValidKey(keyCode) {
  const validKeys = [9, 91, 20, 18, 17, 37];
  return validKeys.includes(keyCode);
}
//...
if (isValidKey(event.keyCode)) ...
```