# Match specific word inside string url of file path

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a system path URL in the form of string from which I have to find the specific keyword "System". How can I achieve this? either by regex or any other way.

```
var key = "System";
var url = "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.PhotoIngestService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.PhotoIngestService";
```

Now url has word "System". I need a function which detects the key in url. If exist it return true.

Comment: I dont understand, can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: If "key" exists in "url" it must return true. i just need true or false.

Comment: try `var keyExists = url.includes(key);`

Comment: You can simply use `indexOf` method: `if(url.indexOf('System') !== 1) { //Some code }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `indexOf()`, returns the position of the string in the other string. If not found, it will return -1.

```js
var key = "System";
var url = "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.PhotoIngestService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.PhotoIngestService";
var isExists = url.indexOf(key) !== -1;
console.log(isExists);
```

Comment: Why downvote here ? Please give a reason.

Answer (score -1):

No need for regex.

```
    var key = "System"
    var url = "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.PhotoIngestService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.PhotoIngestService"
    var exists = url.contains(key)  //returns true

    var exists2 = url.indexOf(key) !== -1   //returns true
```

Comment: I am getting error url.contains is not a function

Comment: @vaidya Strange, I added another function.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is using [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) that returns **true** or **false** (not an index), I think is more clear and more maintainable for this purpose.

**But as we can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Browser_compatibility), it is not supported by IE now.** [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill#Polyfill) the Polyfill made by MDN.

About the difference between `includes()` and `indexOf()` you could read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370222/array-prototype-includes-vs-array-prototype-indexof).

And here an example:

```js
var key = "System";
var url = "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.PhotoIngestService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.PhotoIngestService";

var isPresent = url.includes(key);

console.log(isPresent);
```