# check for character in var using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I amend this to check that `x` also contains `@`?
I've tried using includes() but that does not work.

I realise this is probably simple but I just can't seem to get it

EDIT

using either includes() or indexof() results in this error:

> "'); debugger" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only
>   identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

```
 var x = document.getElementById('emailEntry').value;

    var doesContain = x.includes('@');

    if (x == null || x == "" || !doesContain) {
        document.getElementById('message').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "Email must not be blank";
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code with includes? If the input is a string then it should definitely work with includes()

Comment: Should work like if( ... || x.includes("@")) { ... }

Comment: @AjayGupta `includes()` is for arrays, they want `indexOf()` instead

Comment: Split the string and find that character in array.

Comment: I doubt that includes() only works for arrays. Check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: `x.split('').indexOf('@') !== -1` try this

Comment: @AjayGupta you're right, my mistake. The MDN has two separate entries, one for arrays, one for strings.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov That's one way of doing it. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35370411/8349557