# Boolean switch from ANY to ALL for tag system

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic

I have an array of items `items[]`. Each one has a boolean property `filtered` and a property that is an array called `tags[]`.

I also have another array: `selected_tags`.

With this loop, I can filter all items based on the selected tags:

```
items.forEach(function (item) {

    if (selected_tags.length > 0)
        tag_filter = !selected_tags.some(tag => item.tags.includes(tag));

    // ... other_filter = something else...

    item.filtered = !(!tag_filter && !other_filter);

});
```

This works with a ANY logic (if any tag is in the selected ones, show the item). I'd like to do this with an ALL logic (if all the selected tags are in the item tags, then show it).

So, naturally, I was wondering if includes can do something like this:

```
[1,2,3].includes([1,2,3])

[1,2,3].includes(1,2,3)

tag_filter = item.tags.includes(selected_tags);
```

But it gives false.

Can I do this while keeping it as a simple one liner that returns `tag_filter = true` if filtered and `false` if not?

Comment: `!(!tag_filter && !other_filter)` using DeMorgan's law, this can be transformed to the a lot more readable `tag_filter || other_filter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead of .some()

Eg:

```
[1,2,3].every(x => [1,2,3].includes(x))
```

Also, you can change

```
item.filtered = !(!tag_filter && !other_filter)
```

to

```
item.filtered = tag_filter || other_filter
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array::every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
[1, 2, 3].every(function(item) { return [1, 2, 3].includes(item)) }
```

Or the same for ES6:

```
[1, 2, 3].every(item => [1, 2, 3].includes(item))
```

Comment: `.includes` is not in ES5, so the first piece of code is already ES6.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are checking if one array is subset of other. For this you need to use `every()` and `includes()`. The time complexity will be O(m * n)

```js
function isSubsetOf(a, b){
  return b.every(x => a.includes(x));
}
console.log(isSubsetOf([1,2,3], [1,2,3]))
console.log(isSubsetOf([1,2,3], [1,2,3, 4]))
```

For linear `O(N)` time-complexity first convert the main array to `Set` and then use `Set.prototype.has`

```js
function isSubsetOf(a, b){
  a = new Set(a)
  return b.every(x => a.has(x));
}
console.log(isSubsetOf([1,2,3], [1,2,3]))
console.log(isSubsetOf([1,2,3], [1,2,3, 4]))
```

Answer (score 1):

So basically, you're looking for something more strict than `some()`, that is I'd say `every()`. So simply change this:

```
tag_filter = !selected_tags.some(tag => item.tags.includes(tag));
```

To this:

```
tag_filter = !selected_tags.every(tag => item.tags.indexOf(tag) !== -1);
```

This piece `item.tags.indexOf(tag) !== -1` can be read as "`tag` exists in `item.tags` so it's index is not -1".

Hope this helps!

Comment: `item.tags.indexOf(tag) !== -1` why do that when the code already uses `.includes`?

Comment: @VLAZ good point, it's just that I'm used to `.indexOf()` more often though they don't differ much according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370222/array-prototype-includes-vs-array-prototype-indexof).