# I have to use includes or Indexof at place of in?

Tags: angular

I have to use includes or indexof in place of in, does it effect the application.
Below is the code

```
if (replacementKey in this.replacementParts){
--conditional statememnts
}
```

Comment: why do you need to find index and check if it's -1.Simply use includes

Comment: You might want to look at this already asked question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370222/array-prototype-includes-vs-array-prototype-indexof
I hope this answers to your query.