# Why does [NaN].includes(NaN) return true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, nan

I'm familiar with `NaN` being "weird" in JavaScript, i.e., `NaN === NaN` always returns `false`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23666623/4574731). So one should not make `===` comparisons to check for `NaN`, but use isNaN(..) instead.

So I was surprised to discover that

```
> [NaN].includes(NaN)
true
```

This seems inconsistent. Why have this behavior?

How does it even work? Does the `includes` method specifically check `isNaN`?

Comment: you would like to read this post
https://github.com/tc39/proposal-Array.prototype.includes/issues/29

Comment: `This seems inconsistent,`  Yes, it does seem strange.  NaN is not equal to anything including NaN, apart from X.  But I assume it's chosen here because if it didn't return true, having NaN in the array would then be pointless as it would never be found.

Comment: @Keith it can be found with `.some()`. It's just a bit strange that *this* method was decided to actually work with `NaN` which is different to basically anything else. Aside from map and set. For those, it *does* make sense to treat `NaN` as the same value, otherwise the data structures become very useless.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

According to [MDN's document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#return_value) say that

> Note: Technically speaking, *`includes()`* uses the **`sameValueZero`**
> algorithm to determine whether the given element is found.

```js
const x = NaN, y = NaN;
console.log(x == y); // false                -> using ‘loose’ equality
console.log(x === y); // false               -> using ‘strict’ equality
console.log([x].indexOf(y)); // -1 (false)   -> using ‘strict’ equality
console.log(Object.is(x, y)); // true        -> using ‘Same-value’ equality
console.log([x].includes(y)); // true        -> using ‘Same-value-zero’ equality
```

---

### More detailed explanation:

1. [Same-value-zero equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#same-value-zero_equality) similar to [same-value equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#same-value_equality), *but +0 and −0 are considered equal*.
2. *Same-value equality* is provided by the [Object.is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) method: The only difference between `Object.is()` and `===` is in ***their treatment of signed zeroes and NaNs.***

[image]

---

### Additional resources:

- [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/9071943)
- [Array.prototype.includes vs. Array.prototype.indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35370222/9071943)
- [Are +0 and -0 the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66848243/9071943)

Comment: I've just added `additional resources & Re-arrange sample code to make it clearer as well as more understandable`. As we may be familiar with `lose & strict equality comparison`, but I want to list out all of them to help us have the overall comparison between them. @IMSoP

Answer (score 27):

The `.includes()` method uses [SameValueZero](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevaluezero) algorithm for checking the equality of two values and it considers the `NaN` value to be equal to itself.

The [SameValueZero](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevaluezero) algorithm is similar to [SameValue](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevalue) algorithm, but the only difference is that the [SameValueZero](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevaluezero) algorithm considers `+0` and `-0` to be equal.

The `Object.is()` method uses [SameValue](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-samevalue) and it returns true for `NaN`.

```js
console.log(Object.is(NaN, NaN));
```

The behavior of `.includes()` method is slightly different from the `.indexOf()` method; the `.indexOf()` method uses strict equality comparison to compare values and strict equality comparison doesn't consider `NaN` to be equal to itself.

```js
console.log([NaN].indexOf(NaN));
```

Information about different equality checking algorithms can be found at MDN:

[MDN - Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Answer (score 18):

## Specs

This appears to be part of the [`Number::sameValueZero` abstract operation](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-numeric-types-number-sameValue):

> #### 6.1.6.1.15 Number::sameValueZero ( *x*, *y* )
>
> 1. If *x* is **NaN** and *y* is **NaN**, return **true**.
>
> [...]

This operation is required to be part of the [`Array#includes()`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-array.prototype.includes) check which does:

> #### 22.1.3.13 Array.prototype.includes ( *searchElement* [ , *fromIndex* ] )
>
> [...]
>
> 8. Repeat, while *k* < *len*
>    a. Let *elementK* be the result of ? Get(*O*, ! ToString(*k*)).
>    b. If SameValueZero(*searchElement*, *elementK*) is **true**, return **true**.
>    c. Set k to k + 1.
> 9. Return **false**.
>
> [...]

Where the [`SameValueZero` operation](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-samevaluezero) will delegate to the one for numbers at step 2:

> #### 7.2.12 SameValueZero ( *x*, *y* )
>
> [...]
>
> 1. If Type(*x*) is different from Type(*y*), return **false**.
> 2. If Type(*x*) is Number or BigInt, then
>    a. Return ! Type(*x*)::sameValueZero(*x*, *y*).
> 3. Return ! SameValueNonNumeric(*x*, *y*).

For comparison [`Array#indexOf()`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-array.prototype.indexof) will use [Strict Equality Comparison](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) which is why it behaves differently:

```js
const arr = [NaN];
console.log(arr.includes(NaN)); // true
console.log(arr.indexOf(NaN));  // -1
```

---

## Other similar situations

Other operations that use `SameValueZero` for comparison are in sets and maps:

```js
const s = new Set();

s.add(NaN);
s.add(NaN);

console.log(s.size);     // 1
console.log(s.has(NaN)); // true

s.delete(NaN);

console.log(s.size);     // 0
console.log(s.has(NaN)); // false
```

```js
const m = new Map();

m.set(NaN, "hello world");
m.set(NaN, "hello world");

console.log(m.size);     // 1
console.log(m.has(NaN)); // true

m.delete(NaN);

console.log(m.size);     // 0
console.log(m.has(NaN)); // false
```

---

## History

The [`SameValueZero` algorithm first appears in the ECMAScript 6 specifications](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-samevaluezero) but it is more verbose. It still has the same meaning and still has an explicit:

> 7.2.10 SameValueZero(*x*, *y*)
>
> [...]
>
> 6. If Type(*x*) is Number, then
>    a. If *x* is **NaN** and *y* is **NaN**, return **true**.
>    [...]

[ECMAScript 5.1 only has a `SameValue` algorithm](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-9.12) which still treats `NaN` equal to `NaN`. The only difference with `SameValueZero` is how `+0` and `-0` are treated: `SameValue` returns `false` for them, while `SameValueZero` returns `true`.

`SameValue` is mostly used for internal object operation, so it is almost inconsequential for writing JavaScript code. A lot of the uses of `SameValue` are when working with object keys and there are no numeric values.

The `SameValue` operation is directly exposed in ECMAScript 6 as that is what `Object.is()` uses:

```js
console.log(Object.is(NaN, NaN)); // true
console.log(Object.is(+0, -0));   // false
```

Of slight interest is that `WeakMap` and `WeakSet` also use `SameValue` rather than `SameValueZero` that `Map` and `Set` use for comparison. However, `WeakMap` and `WeakSet` only allow objects as unique members, so attempting to add a `NaN` or `+0` or `-0` or other primitives leads to an error.

Comment: Does "If *x* is **NaN**" mean exactly the same as "if `isNaN(x)`"?  Or does it only refer to the single NaN value produced by `NaN` and not the entire set of NaN values?

Comment: @BenVoigt it's essentially the same as `if (Number.isNaN(x))`. Well, that would be the JavaScript equivalent. The algorithm steps are in pseudocode. The implementation is supposed to check if `x` is the literal value for `NaN`. There is only one of it in but different things can convert to it (e.g., `Number("apple")`). Edit: [ref for NaN](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-nan).

Comment: There definitely are multiple NaN bit patterns in IEEE-754, and I believe you can transfer IEEE-754 values into Javascript by using e.g. a typed buffer.  So my question is, does SameValueZero treat two different NaN bit patterns as equal or unequal?

Comment: @BenVoigt ah, I guess that is where my knowledge of IEEE-754 stretches thin. But according to the spec `NaN` is a `NaN` even if it's not equal to itself. There should only be one conceptually. I suppose implementations are free to use as many `NaN` values as they want but if the algorithm says `x is NaN` it means be any valid `NaN` value.

Answer (score 8):

In [7.2.16 Strict Equality Comparison](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-strict-equality-comparison), there is the following note:

> **NOTE**
>
> This algorithm differs from the [SameValue](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-samevalue) Algorithm in its treatment of signed zeroes and NaNs.

This means for `Array#includes` a different comparison function than for a strict comparison:

[22.1.3.13 Array.prototype.includes](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-array.prototype.includes) under

> **NOTE 3**
>
> The **includes** method intentionally differs from the similar **indexOf** method in two ways. First, it uses the [SameValueZero](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-samevaluezero) algorithm, instead of [Strict Equality Comparison](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-strict-equality-comparison), allowing it to detect **NaN** array elements. Second, it does not skip missing array elements, instead of treating them as **undefined**.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see reading [include documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), it does use the `sameValueZero` algorithm to work, so as its [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#same-value-zero_equality) say, it gives a `True` value when comparing NaN and I quote:

> We can see from the sameness comparisons table below that this is due to the way that `Object.is` handles NaN. Notice that if Object.is(NaN, NaN) evaluated to false, we could say that it fits on the loose/strict spectrum as an even stricter form of triple equals, one that distinguishes between -0 and +0. The NaN handling means this is untrue, however. Unfortunately, `Object.is` has to be thought of in terms of its specific characteristics, rather than its looseness or strictness with regard to the equality operators.