# .includes() not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

This code does not work in internet explorer. Any alternative?

```
"abcde".includes("cd")
```

Comment: Two years later IE still doesn't support it.

Comment: Waiting for IE to get better is like... waiting for IE to get better.

Comment: @nueverest You mean 3 years right? :D

Comment: Someone do everyone a favor and delete the repo(s) for IE. Just end it.

Comment: another 2 years - IE still doesn't support it

Comment: Can't we unleash serial killers to wipe out IE developers? Just asking

Comment: @AniketInge Wrong target. The root cause of that problem is elsewhere and very likely unable to think like a developer.

Comment: @Yunnosch MS has some really smart people. Unfortunately, their greed and lust for owning the web, in the past, is what made IE suck and be where it's today. Mostly likely the code is a mess. That said, IE could just make and load the SHIMs to at the very least, support the JS standards. :-( Sigh!

Comment: @AniketInge Exactly. The developers are not to blame. It was for a long time a policy to be incompatible to standards. Rumor has it that this  is changing....

Comment: Microsoft has announced that its apps and services will stop supporting IE 11 on August 17, 2021 but it will still receive security updates for supporting legacy intranet sites.

Comment: And another year

Answer (score 152, accepted):

`String.prototype.includes` is, as you write, not supported in Internet Explorer (or Opera).

Instead you can use `String.prototype.indexOf`. `#indexOf` returns the index of the first character of the substring if it is in the string, otherwise it returns `-1`. (Much like the Array equivalent)

```
var myString = 'this is my string';
myString.indexOf('string');
// -> 11

myString.indexOf('hello');
// -> -1
```

MDN has a polyfill for `includes` using `indexOf`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill

EDIT: Opera supports `includes` as of [version 28](https://dev.opera.com/blog/opera-28/).

EDIT 2: Current versions of Edge supports the method. (as of 2019)

Comment: Is include() the only function which is not supported by IE? Or there are other typescript or JavaScript functions which are not supported by IE?

Comment: If we need a `Boolean`, we can `(myString.indexOf('string') > -1) // to get a boolean true or false`

Answer (score 39):

Or just put this in a Javascript file and have a good day  :)

```
String.prototype.includes = function (str) {
  var returnValue = false;

  if (this.indexOf(str) !== -1) {
    returnValue = true;
  }

  return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: If you use this polyfill, do not iterate your string with `for...in`, it will iterate over `String.prototype.includes` if it is defined like this.

Comment: Shorter version: `return this.indexOf(str) !== -1;`

Comment: For arrays: Array.prototype.includes = function (elt) { return this.indexOf(elt) !== -1; }

Answer (score 11):

includes() is not supported by most browsers. Your options are either to use

**-polyfill from MDN**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

or to use

**-indexof()**

```
var str = "abcde";
var n = str.indexOf("cd");
```

Which gives you n=2

This is widely supported.

Comment: If you use the polyfill from MDN, _do not iterate your string with `for...in`!_, it will iterate over `String.prototype.includes` if you define it like that.

Answer (score 9):

**Problem:**

Try running below(without solution) **from Internet Explorer** and see the result.

```js
console.log("abcde".includes("cd"));
```

**Solution:**

Now run below solution and check the result

```js
if (!String.prototype.includes) {//To check browser supports or not
  String.prototype.includes = function (str) {//If not supported, then define the method
    return this.indexOf(str) !== -1;
  }
}
console.log("abcde".includes("cd"));
```

Answer (score 4):

This one may be better and shorter:

```
function stringIncludes(a, b) {
    return a.indexOf(b) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: indexOf is not supported by IE

Comment: It works perfectly fine in IE11. Maybe it doesn't in IE10, but there are hardly people still using that version nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when working in Angular 5. In order to make it work directly without writing a polyfill yourself, just add the following line to polyfills.ts file:

```
import "core-js/es7/array"
```

Also, `tsconfig.json` lib section might be relevant:

```
"lib": [
  "es2017",
  "dom"
],
```

Comment: You my friend are a complete lifesaver!

Answer (score 3):

For react:

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import 'core-js/es5';
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es7';
```

Issue resolve for - includes(), find(), and so on..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using the `Array.prototype.include()` in javascript you can use this script:
[github-script-ie-include](https://github.com/Mteixeira88/IE-include-script)
That converts automatically the include() to the match() function if it detects IE.

Other option is using always the`string.match(Regex(expression))`

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
function stringIncludes(a, b) {
      return a.indexOf(b) !== -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because ie does not support includes so
Make a dot function and use it just like es6 includes() in es5 as below :

```
String.prototype.includes = function (str) {
 return this.indexOf(str) !== -1;
}
```

Following is the string

```
var myString = 'this is my string';
```

Checking the match as following:

```
console.log(myString.includes('string')); // true
console.log(myString.includes('street')); //false
```

Now you can add this for ES5 using same *indexOf* in *includes* way

Answer (score -1):

You can do the same with !! and ~ operators

```
 var myString = 'this is my string';

 !!~myString.indexOf('string');
 // -> true

 !!~myString.indexOf('hello');
 // -> false
```

here's the explanation of the two operators (!! and ~ )

[What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/