# identify widget type from name

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Does anyone have a way to determine the type of widget from its name/ID? For example if `"my_text"` is a `textInput` widget, then I would like to be able to call:

```
is.textInput("my_text")
```

and be returned `TRUE`. Or to call

```
widget.type("my_list")
```

and be returned `"textInput"`. But neither of these functions exist.

I have looked through all the functions in the `shiny` and `shinyWidgets` packages and don't see anything to this extent. There are some back-end functions like `session$sendInputMessage()` that are not intended for users but might assist.

My naive solution is to try something like the following (sorry if my `tryCatch()` syntax is not quite right, I don't use it very often):

```
is.textInput <- function(widget_id){
    out <- tryCatch(
        {
        # attempt to treat it as a textInput, change it and change it back
        tmp <- input[[widget_id]]
        updateTextInput(session, widget_id, value = character(0))
        updateTextInput(session, widget_id, value = tmp)
        },
        error=function(cond) { return("NO") },
        warning=function(cond) { return("NO") },
        finally={}
    )
    # if error message happens then not textInput
    if(out == "NO")
        return("FALSE")
    # if no error message then is textInput
    return("TRUE")
}
```

But I would rather not be creating deliberate errors/exceptions. And I do not want a logical check to be making changes to the state of the app.

Other suggests for how I might accomplish this?

Comment: Opening a bounty on this as the browser dependence in @BigDataScientist's solution does not work with my application.

Comment: sry to hear, could you ellaborate what is the missing functionality in your application?

Comment: I am not guaranteed that the user will make use of Chrome. In fact: with the IT controls on the environment, I anticipate about half of use will be via internet explorer or RStudio viewer. In the absence of a better answer, I will happily grant you the bounty - your answer has made me consider several new possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**
I modified a line in the javascript code to make it IE/Rstudio Viewer compatible. IE/Viewer threw an error, because the function `include()` is not supported by them, see [.includes() not working in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36574351/includes-not-working-in-internet-explorer). Instead `indexOf()` can be used.

You could use javascript to inspect the input element by id. The element can be found via 
`document.getElementById()` and then you can identify the type via `getAttribute('class')` and `getAttribute('type')`.

The results can be "sent" to R via `Shiny.onInputChange('inputType', ...);` and used in R via `input$inputType`.

A first example of the function would be:

```
getWidgetType <- function(widgetId){
  paste0(
    "elem = document.getElementById('", widgetId,"');
    var message;
    if(elem == null){
      message = 'No input with id = ", widgetId," exists.'
    }else{
      // RStudio Viewer + IE workaround (dont have .include())
      if(elem.getAttribute('class').indexOf('js-range-slider') > -1){ 
        message = 'slider'
      }else if (elem.nodeName == 'SELECT'){
        message = 'select'
      }else{
        message = elem.getAttribute('type');
      }
    }
    Shiny.onInputChange('inputType', message)
    "
  )
}
```

Note that i made an example for four inputs: numeric, text, selectInput, and sliderInput. If you add additional inputs you might have to inspect other attributes as well.

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  textInput("textInput", "id = textInput", "text"),
  numericInput("numInput", "id = numInput", 10),
  sliderInput("slideInput", "id = slideInput", 1, 10, 5),

  hr(style = "height:1px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;"),
  textInput("widgetType", "widget type by id", "textInput"),
  textOutput("widgetId")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$widgetId <- renderText({
    runjs(getWidgetType(input$widgetType))
    input$inputType
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This solution only partially works for me. When a widget name is typed in the `widgetType` textbox, the `textOutput` does not update. Suggestions?

Comment: somehow for me, the textoutput doesnt show in viewer pane, but it works as expected (and updates) when i open it in chrome. Which setting are you using?

Comment: You are right. Sorry, I was only testing in the RStudio viewer. I can confirm it works as expected in Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer (the only other browser I have on hand).