# Get parent value if particular text exists in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to search text "country" in below object.

```js
{
  "plus_code": {
    "compound_code": "F28M+H8 Gurugram, Haryana, India",
    "global_code": "7JWVF28M+H8"
  },
  "results": [{
    "address_components": [{
      "long_name": "53/1",
      "short_name": "53/1",
      "types": ["premise"]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Block B",
      "short_name": "Block B",
      "types": ["political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_3"]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Acharya Puri",
      "short_name": "Acharya Puri",
      "types": ["political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_2"]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Sector 12",
      "short_name": "Sector 12",
      "types": ["political", "sublocality", "sublocality_level_1"]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Gurugram",
      "short_name": "Gurugram",
      "types": ["locality", "political"]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Gurgaon",
      "short_name": "Gurgaon",
      "types": ["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Haryana",
      "short_name": "HR",
      "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
    }, {
      "long_name": "India",
      "short_name": "IN",
      "types": ["country", "political"]
    }, {
      "long_name": "122001",
      "short_name": "122001",
      "types": ["postal_code"]
    }],
    "formatted_address": "53/1, Block B, Acharya Puri, Sector 12, Gurugram, Haryana 122001, India",
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 28.4662822,
        "lng": 77.03326179999999
      },
      "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 28.4676311802915,
          "lng": 77.0346107802915
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 28.4649332197085,
          "lng": 77.0319128197085
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJ2Up-YTUYDTkR3vg0BXrwyXI",
    "plus_code": {
      "compound_code": "F28M+G8 Gurugram, Haryana, India",
      "global_code": "7JWVF28M+G8"
    },
    "types": ["street_address"]
  }],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

In the above object which has `types": ["country","political" ]` I want its parent variable `short_name` value in variable.

Right now I'm using the following code:

```js
if (locationData.status == "OK") {
  var data = locationData.results;
  var dataLength = data.length;
  if (data[dataLength - 1].hasOwnProperty("address_components")) {
    var address_components = data[dataLength - 1].address_components;
    var countryCode = address_components[0].short_name.toLocaleLowerCase();
    if (countryCode && pageData.hasOwnProperty(countryCode)) {
      localStorage.setItem("el_country", countryCode);
      location.href = pageData[countryCode];
    } else {
      location.href = defaultPage;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` to find entities within the `results[].address_components` array which contain the `country` string within their `types`. Try this:

```js
// Note: I removed a lot of the unnecesary properties from the object 
// for this demo for the sake of brevity

let locationData = {
  "results": [{
    "address_components": [{
      "long_name": "Haryana",
      "short_name": "HR",
      "types": ["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]
    }, {
      "long_name": "India",
      "short_name": "IN",
      "types": ["country", "political"]
    }, {
      "long_name": "122001",
      "short_name": "122001",
      "types": ["postal_code"]
    }]
  }],
  "status": "OK"
}

// IE-friendly version:
// let countries = locationData.results[0].address_components.filter(function(o) {    
//   return o.types.includes('country');
// });

let countries = locationData.results[0].address_components.filter(o => o.types.includes('country'));
let shortName = countries[0].short_name;

console.log(shortName);
```

Comment: How to support below function for IE11, where filter, arrow and include function is not supported?  
"let countries = locationData.results[0].address_components.filter(o => o.types.includes('country'));"

Comment: You can revert to an anonymous function for IE support. I updated the answer to show you how to do this

Comment: I am getting console error in IE11 "Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'" for following code:

return o.types.includes('country');

Comment: IE doesn't support `includes()`. You can use `indexOf()` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36574502/519413