# How to create a searchbar with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hello Im trying to create a searchbar for my table with javascript and works but with some issues. The problem is when I try to search in two rows. For example if I only search in Name works! but if I search Name and Last Name doesn't work.

Here is my js function

```
var textbuscar = document.getElementById("buscar");
textbuscar.onkeyup = function() {
  buscar(this);
}

function buscar(inputbuscar) {
  var valorabuscar = (inputbuscar.value).toLowerCase().trim();
  var tabla_tr = document.getElementById("tabla").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].rows;
  for (var i = 0; i < tabla_tr.length; i++) {
    var tr = tabla_tr[i];
    var textotr = (tr.innerText).toLowerCase();
    tr.className = (textotr.indexOf(valorabuscar) >= 0) ? "mostrar" : "ocultar";
  }
}
```

Here is a runnable copy:

```js
var textbuscar = document.getElementById("buscar");
textbuscar.onkeyup = function(){
 buscar(this);
}
function buscar(inputbuscar){
 var valorabuscar = (inputbuscar.value).toLowerCase().trim();
 var tabla_tr = document.getElementById("tabla").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].rows;
 for(var i=0; i<tabla_tr.length; i++){
  var tr = tabla_tr[i];
  var textotr = (tr.innerText).toLowerCase();
  tr.className = (textotr.indexOf(valorabuscar)>=0)?"mostrar":"ocultar";
 }
}
```

```css
.mostar{display:block;}
.ocultar{display:none;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<linl rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1 class="page-header">
My Table
    </h1>
    <!-- TABLA INICIA -->
    <table id="tabla" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:160px">Nombre</th>
          <th>Apellido</th>
          <th style="width:220px">Profesion</th>
          <th style="width:140px">Sueldo</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4">
            <input id="buscar" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba algo para filtrar" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Juan</td>
          <td>Perez Patiño</td>
          <td>Marketing Empresarial</td>
          <td class="text-right">S/. 9000.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Alberto</td>
          <td>Gonzales Flores</td>
          <td>Derecho</td>
          <td class="text-right">S/. 4000.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Gustavo</td>
          <td>Bueno Bravo</td>
          <td>Derecho</td>
          <td class="text-right">S/. 7000.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Enrique</td>
          <td>Pacheco Perez</td>
          <td>Derecho</td>
          <td class="text-right">S/. 12000.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jaime</td>
          <td>Andrade Gonzales</td>
          <td>Economia</td>
          <td class="text-right">S/. 7500.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Andrea</td>
          <td>Loayza Perez</td>
          <td>Medicina Humana</td>
          <td class="text-right">S/. 7500.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Elvira</td>
          <td>Gonzales Perez</td>
          <td>Ingeniería de Sistema</td>
          <td class="text-right">S/. 7500.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Joseph</td>
          <td>Rodriguez Pacheco</td>
          <td>Ingeniería de Software</td>
          <td class="text-right">S/. 8200.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Pedro</td>
          <td>kuczynski</td>
          <td>Economista</td>
          <td class="text-right">S/. 250000.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Alan</td>
          <td>García Perez</td>
          <td>Derecho</td>
          <td class="text-right">S/. 120000.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jose</td>
          <td>Villanueva Salvador</td>
          <td>Medicina Humana</td>
          <td class="text-right">S/. 2900.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Alberto</td>
          <td>Lozano García</td>
          <td>Medicina Humana</td>
          <td class="text-right">S/. 2900.00</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- TABLA FINALIZA -->
    
    
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[A demo at jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkL17Lz8/6/) to play with.

Comment: You are searching two separatelly words in differents cells, so it will not work. For example, if you search for `Jose Salva` in your mind `Jose Villanueva Salvador` will match, but the truth is that javascript is searching for the string `Jose Salva` inside a single cell. You need to split the searching string, search each word independently and then mix the results.

Comment: So this code works only searching in one cell right?

Comment: Yes, it only find single-cell ocurrences

Answer (score 0):

To give you a headstart, I modified your function a little bit. This still doesn't work the way you want, but it should guide you with an idea:

```
function buscar(inputbuscar){
    var valorabuscar = (inputbuscar.value).toLowerCase().trim();

    var arraydevalores = valorabuscar.split(" ");
    console.log(arraydevalores); //CHECK WHAT THIS LOGS

    var tabla_tr = document.getElementById("tabla").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].rows;
        console.log(findOne(arraydevalores, tabla_tr));
    for(var i=0; i<tabla_tr.length; i++){
        var tr = tabla_tr[i];
        var textotr = (tr.innerText).toLowerCase();
        tr.className = (textotr.indexOf(valorabuscar)>=0)?"mostrar":"ocultar";
    }
}
```

I split your `valorabuscar` variable where any spaces are, so now you have an array of the terms that the user is searching for sepparately in an array that looks like this:

```
["juan", "pérez", "patiño"]
```

This array is easier to manipulate so as to compare it with your table and return whatever's more similar to it. Good luck!

PS: Here's an appropriate question to help you continue: [Check if an array contains any element of another array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-elements-in-another-array-in-javascript)