# Angularjs check if two arrays have different elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array `$scope.blinkingBoxes=[1,3,2]`

I have another array called `$scope.clickedBoxes` and I push few values in it.

Now `if(angular.equals($scope.blinkingBoxes, $scope.clickedBoxes)){doSomething()}` checks if the both the arrays are same (i.e. same elements in same order)

However I want to check if the second array do not contain any element from first array and perform some action. **How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript

Comment: It says 'any' element and I want 'none'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such built-in function

you can use this

```
angular.forEach(array1, function(value, key) {
angular.forEach(array2, function(value_1, key_1) {
    if (value === value_1) {
        // condition or action
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0;
angular.forEach($scope.blinkingBoxes, function(value, key) { 
    if(value.indexOf($scope.clickedBoxes) == -1) {
        //not in same order or not same elements action goes here
        count++;
    }
});

if(count == $scope.blinkingBoxes.length) {
    //second array do not contain any element from first array, action goes here
}
```