# Ensure all values in array are in another array

Tags: ecmascript-6

I wish to check that all the values in `event` are included in `state`. Is so the function should return true, else false. What is a nice way of doing this?

```
const state = [1,2,4,5,6,7]
const event = [1,2]
if(state.contains(event))(}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16312528/218196

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) array methods:

```js
const state = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const event = [1, 2];
console.log(event.every(x => state.includes(x)));
```