# Check if an array of strings contains a substring

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
array = ["123", "456", "#123"]
```

I want to find the element which contains the substring `"#"`. I tried `array.includes("#")` and `array.indexOf("#")` but it didn't work.

How can I check if any of the strings in this array contain the substring `"#"`?

Comment: try `array.some(x => x.includes(y))`

Comment: I think it would be more like `array.find(item => item.includes('#'))`

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Because includes will compare '#' with each array element.

Let's try with [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=control) or [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=control) if you want to find if you want to get exactly element

```js
var array = ["123", "456", "#123"];

var el = array.find(a =>a.includes("#"));

console.log(el)
```

Comment: the "some" method is very useful for a case such as this

Comment: Using "some" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript

Comment: this only find 1st occurence. i wnt to get all ocurrences

Comment: let's use `map` instead of `find` for your demand @shorif2000 `var el = array.map(a => a.includes("#") ? a : false).filter(Boolean);`

Comment: What @taile you would do, if the case is vice versa. eg. var array = ["123", "456", "#123"];
 and we have '1234' for comparison. As first 3 chars '123' are in array. This should return ['123', '#123]. How can we achieve this?

Comment: you should use filter in this case @VishalKumar `array.filter(a =>a.includes("123"));`

Answer (score 18):

There appears to be multiple questions here since the title and post body differ. Do you want to know if the array has an element or do you want to get the element itself? If you want to get an element, which one(s) do you want--the first occurrence, the last occurrence or an array of all occurrences?

This post is intended as a resource for future visitors who might not necessarily want to `find` (i.e. return the first element from the start of the array that matches a predicate) as the top answer shows. To elaborate on that answer, there's a gotcha with indiscriminately replacing `some` with `find` in a boolean context--the element returned may be falsey as in

```js
if ([5, 6, 0].find(e => e < 3)) { // fix: use `some` instead of `find`
  console.log("you might expect this to run");
}
else {
  console.log("but this actually runs " +
    "because the found element happens to be falsey");
}
```

Note that `e => e.includes("#")` can be substituted with any predicate, so it's largely incidental to the question.

The same problem can occur when using `indexOf` in a condition and failing to account for the fact that 0 (the element was found at the first position in the array) is falsey.

---

#### Does any element match the predicate?

```js
const array = ["123", "456", "#123"];
console.log(array.some(e => e.includes("#"))); // true
console.log(array.some(e => e.includes("foobar"))); // false
```

[MDN: Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

#### Does every element match the predicate?

```js
const array = ["123", "456", "#123"];
console.log(array.every(e => e.includes("#"))); // false
console.log(array.every(e => /\d/.test(e))); // true
```

[MDN: Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

#### What is the first element that matches the predicate?

```js
const array = ["123", "456", "#123", "456#"];
console.log(array.find(e => e.includes("#"))); // "#123"
console.log(array.find(e => e.includes("foobar"))); // undefined
```

[MDN: Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

#### What is the index of the first element that matches the predicate?

```js
const array = ["123", "456", "#123", "456#"];
console.log(array.findIndex(e => e.includes("#"))); // 2
console.log(array.findIndex(e => e.includes("foobar"))); // -1
```

[MDN: Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

#### What are all the elements that match the predicate?

```js
const array = ["123", "456", "#123", "456#"];
console.log(array.filter(e => e.includes("#"))); // ["#123", "456#"]
console.log(array.filter(e => e.includes("foobar"))); // []
```

[MDN: Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

#### What is the last element that matches the predicate?

```js
const array = ["123", "456", "#123", "456#"];
console.log(array.findLast(e => e.includes("#"))); // "456#"
console.log(array.findLast(e => e.includes("foobar"))); // undefined
```

[MDN: Array.prototype.findLast()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findLast)

#### What is the index of the last element that matches the predicate?

```js
const array = ["123", "456", "#123", "456#"];
console.log(array.findLastIndex(e => e.includes("#"))); // 3
console.log(array.findLastIndex(e => e.includes("foobar"))); // -1
```

[MDN: Array.prototype.findLastIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findLastIndex)

#### What are the indices of all of the elements that match the predicate?

```js
const filterIndices = (a, pred) => a.reduce((acc, e, i) => {
  pred(e, i, a) && acc.push(i);
  return acc;
}, []);

const array = ["123", "456", "#123", "456#"];
console.log(filterIndices(array, e => e.includes("#"))); // [2, 3]
console.log(filterIndices(array, e => e.includes("foobar"))); // []
```

[MDN: Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
array.some((item) => item.includes('#'));
```

It just checks if some item includes '#' - readable and clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use join method:

```
array.join('').indexOf("#")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use filter ().

```
    var array = ["123", "456", "#123"];

    console.log(array.filter(function(item){
        var finder = '#';
        return eval('/'+finder+'/').test(item);
    }));
```

By passing a function you can filter and return the elements that match what you are looking for.

In this example, I made use of eval (), just because to fetch the string use RegExp, but could fetch with the == operator.

Comment: why eval? {}{}{{}

Comment: Use `new RegExp()` instead of `eval`, or even better just use `includes`. If the substring happens to have special regex characters, the regex approach breaks, so this answer is pretty broken on a couple of levels.