# Detect if any element in an array contains a hyphen

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have tried using the includes() function but it returns false for me as follows:

```
<script>
    var fruits = ["Banana-orange", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    console.log(fruits.includes("-")); // returnes false, should be true
</script>
```

As you can see, 'banana-orange' contains a hyphen. I expect the result to return true.

Am I using the wrong function?

Comment: "For arrays, the search value must match an element, You can't match a substring of an element."

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440317/check-if-an-array-of-strings-contains-a-substring-in-javascript answers with filter() and find(). IE this is a duplicate of a broader question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are actually checking is if there is an item in the array fruits which is "-",

I would use a for loop to check, if there is an item of the array which includes '-'.

```
const fruits = ['Banana-orange', 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Mango'];

for (let i = 0; fruits.length; i++) {
    if (fruits[i].includes('-')) return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) compare with the element in the array(full string match in your case). To make it work, join the values in the array with empty space(use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)) and use [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method which searches for a substring.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana-orange", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
console.log(fruits.join('').includes("-"));
```

---

Or use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to iterate and check at least one contains the string using [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana-orange", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
console.log(fruits.some(v => v.includes("-")));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
fruits.some((fruit) => fruit.includes('-'));
```

It just checks if some fruit includes hyphen - readable and clear.

Answer (score -1):

Fruits does not include ‘-‘. Fruits(1) contains ‘-‘.  This is why the includes function does not return anything. Loop through the array instead and test the contents of the array.