# Python check if one of multiple strings contain a substring

Tags: python, string

I have relatively complicated if statements that return `True` if a target string contains a keyword (also a string). Is there a way that as an `elif` I search for the keyword in multiple target strings?

This is my sample code:

```
a = 'i am foo'
b = 'keyword could also be in here'

if 'foo' in 'b':
    out = 1
elif 'foo' in [a,b]:
    out = 2
else:
    out = 3
```

Current behavior: returns 3
Expected behavior: return 2

I know that I could do `elif 'foo' in a or 'foo' in b` but my conditions are already lengthy with any and all statements so that the code becomes rather unreadable when I solve the issue with `or`.

Basically, I'm looking for a pythonic way to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440317/check-if-an-array-of-strings-contains-a-substring) (only not in JavaScript).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't necessarily have to use if-statements, you can do

```
list(filter(lambda x:'foo' in x, [a,b]))
```

which will give you a list of strings containing `'foo'`.
So you if you just want to see IF some string contains your keyword, check if the length of this list is bigger 0, like so:

```
len(list(filter(lambda x:'foo' in x, [a,b]))) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain why `'foo' in [a, b]:` is not evaluating as True.

I am providing this answer as an expansion of the question to see if someone can explain in comments, why `'foo' in [a, b]:` is not evaluating as True.

```
a = 'i am foo'
b = 'keyword could also be in here'

id([a,b]) # Is the ID ao the list in memory it contains the id of a and the id
# of b.
print(f'{id(a)=}')
print(f'{id([a,b][0])=}')
print(f'{id(b)=}')
print(f'{id([a,b][1])=}')

if 'foo' in 'b':
    out = 1
elif 'foo' in [a, b]:  # Does not evaluate as expected
    out = 2
elif 'foo' in str([a, b]):  # Will evaluate but why is it necessary
    out = 4
else:
    out = 3

print(f'{out}')

print(f"{'foo' in 'b'=}")
print(f"{'foo' in [a, b]=}")  # Does not evaluate as expected
print(f"{'foo' in str([a,b])=}")  # Will evaluate but why is it necessary
print(f"{'i am foo' in [a, b]=}")
```

Output:

```
id(a)=2165458290096
id([a,b][0])=2165458290096
id(b)=2165458558672
id([a,b][1])=2165458558672
4
'foo' in 'b'=False
'foo' in [a, b]=False
'foo' in str([a,b])=True
'i am foo' in [a, b]=True
```