# How to perform a dynamic search within a nested array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, search

Let's say that I have a music app that showcases the tracks within a selected playlist. If I'm using React, I would have a state for the `tracklist` which would contain an array of objects. The object would contain information about the track. Here's an example:

```
{
  id: 1
  name: 'Calm Down'
  artist: ['Selena Gomez', 'Rema']
  album: 'Calm Down'
}
```

I have another state for the search text called `searchTerm`. If I'm trying to search for a specific song name, I can write some code like this:

```
function dynamicSearch() {
    return tracklist.filter(track =>
      track.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
}
```

But how do I search for an artist, in this example Selena Gomez, if there's more than one and they're inside an array?

Comment: Make sure your string values in your objects are quoted. Also will `artist` _always_ be an array, or only if there are more than one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you search an array for a substring match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556099/how-do-you-search-an-array-for-a-substring-match)

Comment: [Check if an array of strings contains a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44440317)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Array.prototype.some() to tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test:

```
function dynamicSearch() {
  return tracklist.filter(track =>
    track.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
    track.artist.some(artist =>
      artist.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: This is just the answer I was looking for! Simple and straight-forward. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way. JS Arrays have "includes" method too.

```
function searchByAuthor(autorName) {
  // make artists name lowercased using map and then try to find an author using includes method
  return tracklist.filter(track =>
    track.artist?.map(a => a.toLowerCase()).includes(autorName.toLowerCase()))
}
```

You can read more here - [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

If you need to search track by substring of artist's name the function can be like this:

```
function searchByAuthor(autorName) {
  const result = [];
  tracklist.forEach(track => {
    //Lowercased artist's names
    const trackArtists = track.artist?.map(a => a.toLowerCase());
    // Try to find an artist by a part of the name
    const isArtistFound = trackArtists?.find((a) => a.includes(autorName.toLowerCase())) !== undefined;
    if (isArtistFound) {
      result.push(track);
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let trackList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Calm Down',
    artist: ['Selena Gomez', 'Rema'],
    album: 'Calm Down'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Stir up',
    artist: ['Sir Stir', 'Rema'],
    album: 'Keep stirring'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Sir is stirring',
    artist: ['Sir Stir'],
    album: 'Meet Sir Stir'
  }
];

const searchByArtist = searchTerm => trackList.filter(({ artist }) =>
  artist.join('').toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()));

console.log('Sel =>', searchByArtist('Sel'), '\n\n');
console.log('ema =>', searchByArtist('ema'), '\n\n');
console.log('tir =>', searchByArtist('tir'));
```