# check for multiple Array.includes using or

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I test for multiple .includes with `Array.includes()` in my if statement? The below seems to work on one item, *ie.* `slug-title-one` but ignores the second.

```
if (item.slug.includes('slug-title-one' || 'slug-title-13')) {
     // checks for and displays if either

}
```

Comment: Instead of using includes, I'd go with the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript

Comment: Because `||` evaluates the first string as truthy and so that is what is passed to `includes()`. You have to check both separately. Read the documentation for includes()

Comment: using reduce `['slug-title-one','slug-title-13'].reduce( (a, b) => a && item.slug.includes(b), true)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the `Array.includes` can only test for a single element.

You could reverse your logic though and use

```
if (['slug-title-one','slug-title-13'].some(slug => item.slug.includes(slug))) {
     // checks for and displays if either

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but still on occasion this responds with 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null'

Comment: @Billy that means that the `item.slug` is `null`.

Comment: The problem is sometimes it will be null, but other times not, I don't want the page to break on the rare instances it is null

Comment: wrap the whole `if` in another one the does `if (item.slug) {...} `. Btw this problem would exist in your original attempt as well.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. Here are some ideas:

**Repeat includes**

```
if (item.slug.includes('slug-title-one') || item.slug.includes('slug-title-13')) { ... }
```

**Helper function**

```
if( includes(item.slug, 'slug-title-one', 'slug-title-13') ) { ... }

function includes() {

    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var target = args[0];
    var strs = args.slice(1); // remove first element

    for(var i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
        if(target.includes(strs[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: The OP talks about `Array.includes` which means the `item.slug` is an array. So the regex version wouldn't work.