# Check if certain stings (even with spaces) are in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Trying to compare two arrays and see if existing words (even with spaces) exists in both. See below.

I think I have a rough idea. Thanks ahead for your help!

HTML

```
<meta name="keywords" content="dog, cat, humming bird, shark, king cobra">
```

Jquery

```
var myArray = $("meta[name='keywords']").attr("content");
var myAnimals = ["humming bird","king cobra"];
if (jQuery.inArray(myAnimals, myArray) != -1) {
    alert('animal exists');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if an array contains any element of another array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attr("content")` will return a string. You can use `split(',')` to convert the string into an array. Use `map` to loop thru the array and `trim()` the spaces.

You can use `some()` to loop thru the `myArray` array and use `includes` to check whether an array includes a certain string.

```js
var myArray = $("meta[name='keywords']").attr("content").split(',').map(o => o.trim());
var myAnimals = ["humming bird", "king cobra"];

var result = myArray.some(o => myAnimals.includes(o));
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="keywords" content="dog, cat, humming bird, shark, king cobra">
```

---

If you want to get the actual array elements, you can use `filter()` and `includes()`

```js
var myArray = $("meta[name='keywords']").attr("content").split(',').map(o => o.trim());
var myAnimals = ["humming bird", "king cobra", "owl"];

var result = myArray.filter(o => myAnimals.includes(o));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="keywords" content="dog, cat, humming bird, shark, king cobra">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//split the keywords so it is a real array
var myArray = $("meta[name='keywords']").attr("content").split(', ');
console.log(myArray);

var myAnimals = ["humming bird","king cobra"];

//loop over your animals
myAnimals.forEach(function(animal){
  //check if each animal is in the array
  if (myArray.indexOf(animal) > -1) {
    console.log(animal +' exists!');
  } else {
    console.log(animal +' does not exist!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="keywords" content="dog, cat, humming bird, shark, king cobra">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var myArray = $("meta[name='keywords']").attr("content");
```

to

```
var myArray = $("meta[name='keywords']").attr("content").split(", ");
```

Then your code should work.

Comment: It still won't work. `$.inArray()` doesn't compare two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

After using `.split(', ')` on your `keywords` to create an array,
you could use a function to get all the similar elements:

```js
var myArray = $("meta[name='keywords']").attr("content").split(', ');
var myAnimals = ["humming bird", "king cobra"];

function get_similarities(arrayA, arrayB) {
  var matches = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
    if (arrayB.includes(arrayA[i]))
      matches.push(arrayA[i]);
  }
  return matches;
}

var similarities = get_similarities(myArray, myAnimals);
console.log('Found in both arrays:', similarities);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="keywords" content="dog, cat, humming bird, shark, king cobra">
```

Hope it helps.