# the every method does not work in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Firstly, the `.includes` method does not work with my framework, so I omit this here.
I have `checkIn(el,ar)` function to check if `el` in `ar` like this:

```
function checkIn(el){
var check = false;
   for (i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
     if(el === ar[i]){
     check = true;
     break;
   };
  };
 return check;
 };
```

it works normaly. Then I want to use the `.every` method to check if every element of a given array is in another given array

```
var x = [1,2,3];
var y = [1,2,3,4,5];
var check = x.every(checkIn(y))
```

`check` needs to be true, but it doesn't work?

Comment: y is an array not an element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if an array contains any element of another array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.every` accepts a callback for which the first parameter is an *element of the array being iterated over*. If you want to be able to use

```
x.every(checkIn(y))
```

then `checkIn` should return a function that can then be used as the callback:

```js
function checkIn(containingArr) {
  return item => containingArr.includes(item);
};

var x = [1, 2, 3];
var y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(x.every(checkIn(y))); // every item in x is in y; true
console.log([0].every(checkIn(y))); // 0 is not in y; false
```

Or, to use something similar to your `for` loop:

```js
function checkIn(ar) {
  return el => {
    var check = false;
    for (i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
      if (el === ar[i]) {
        check = true;
        break;
      };
    };
    return check;
  };
}

var x = [1, 2, 3];
var y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(x.every(checkIn(y)));
console.log([0].every(checkIn(y)));
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your `checkIn(el,ar)` does only take `el` so if you're not getting an error you're accessing a global or out-of-scope variable `ar` that may hold data that doesn't make sense in that context.

If you simply want to check if an array contains a specific value there is a really simple way to do it:

```
[1,2,3].includes(3) //true
[1,2,3].includes(6) //false
```

And to extrapolate to a whole array using `.every` requires you to pass a lambda or function, not just a function call, like so:

```
var xs = [1, 2, 3];
var ys = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

xs.every(x => ys.includes(x))
```

where `x => ys.includes(x)` is shorthand for `function(x){return ys.includes(x)}`

or using your `checkIn(el,ar)`

```
xs.every(x => checkIn(x,ys))
```

Comment: I don't want to use th `includes` method here since it does not work with my framework. the satement `el === ar[i] ` is just an example of what I need to do. I just wanna know how the `.every` method work. Sorry for the unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Function `checkIn` looks redundant.

```
function checkIn(el, ar) {
    let check = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if (el === ar[i]) {
            check = true;
            break;
        };
    };
    return check;
};
```

Why not use `Array.prototype.includes`?

BTW, the first parameter of the function `every` should be a `function` but you pass the result of `checkIn`, which type is `boolean`.

We can do like this.

```
x.every((e) => y.includes(e))
```