# Why can't I compare two arrays with "includes"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

Javascript does not allow comparision of arrays using `includes` ?

See this example:

```
let x = [[1,2], [3,4]]
let y = x[0]
let z = [1,2]

console.log(y,z)
// Output: [ 1, 2 ] [ 1, 2 ]
console.log(x.includes(y), x.includes(z))
// Output: true false
```

I would like to have `x.includes(z)` to be `true`.

I was made aware of the qurestion [check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript) by the comments, but it does not answer my question as I want to check if the array has exactly the same elements using `includes` not only some.

Moreover, this question [how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript) does not explain why `includes` does not work. It tells *how* to do it, which is not the point of my question.

Comment: Because they reference to different memory locations

Comment: You can't check arrays directly like that

Comment: You could use `JSON.stringify(x).includes(JSON.stringify(z))` which is true

Comment: There *has* to be a good dupetarget for this... (And adiga found it.)

Comment: I don't want to see if two arrays are equal, like explained in the refered question. That answer question (that I was aware of) did not help me.

Comment: No? Think carefully, how `includes` works, maybe the duped post opens to you too ...

Comment: Looking back, now that I know the answer, the key thing was the fact that in JS the equaliry signs (==) compares addresses in the memory, and `includes` uses == under the hood. The question marked as duplicate has reference to memory only twice and only after the 5th answer or so. Also, one could think it is naive to think that == should behave diferently, but in python, for example, an array (or list) has the == implemented as I was expecting, but clearly in JS it is not, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use includes for the values of the array when they are "primitive types", but not with a whole array.

When you use includes, it checks if the current element of the array is `===` to the element that is passed as an argument.

In your case, it would be checking if `[1,2] === [1,2]` this yields false, and it's because via the `===` comparator you are just checking for the memory reference when applied to arrays.

If you want to do something like comparing for if the whole array is the same probably you are better of using a function like `_. isEqual` from [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual) or implementing your own comparator function.

Answer (score 5):

Because `[1, 2] === [1, 2]` is false. Different arrays are not equal to each other, not even if they have the same contents. (This is true of all objects.)