# How to check an array contains any item of another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two arrays

```
var master= ["1","2","3"];
var arr = ["1","5"];
```

i wanted to check if `arr` contains any item from `master`. Based on [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript) here i have the following code which only works with chrome

```
var found = arr.some(r => master.indexOf(r) >= 0);
```

however it does not work with IE11. IE11 throws error

> JavaScript critical error at line 23, column 44 in
>   https://localhost:44328/js/xxxx.js\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error

I have also tried

```
 var found = arr.some(r => master.includes(r) >= 0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take a classic function, because IE 11 has only ES5, that means no [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) nor [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
var master= ["1", "2", "3"],
    arr = ["1", "5"],
    found = arr.some(function (r) { return master.indexOf(r) >= 0; });

console.log(found);
```