# How to return index of object element matched from a check array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search

i hope the title is properly expressive of the problem i'm trying to solve.  what i need to do is search an object for a matching element from a check array and return the object's index of that match. to whit:

```js
const checkArray = ['18A38', '182B92', '85F33'];    //  these are the values to match
const dataOject = [
  0 => ['id'=>'853K83', 'isGO'=>false],             //  this is the object to search through
  1 => ['id'=>'85F33', 'isGO'=>true],
  2 => ['id'=>'97T223', 'isGO'=>true],
  3 => ['id'=>'18A38', 'isGO'=>false],
  4 => ['id'=>'182B92', 'isGO'=>true],
  ...
];
```

what i need to do is find the matching index so i can then check if the `isGO` flag is set.  this is what i was trying when i dead-ended:

```js
results = checkArray.forEach(function(value, index){
  if (dataObject.findIndex(function(k=> k == value))) results.push(k);
    //  i know 'results.push(k)' is not right, but it's the essence of what i want.  :P
};
```

what i am expecting is that `results` will be an array of indexes that i can then go back and check the `dataObject` for set `isGO` flags; `results` should look like this:

```js
results = [3, 1, 4];
```

but i'm stumped on how to make the `findIndex` complete properly.  i've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098040/checking-if-a-key-exists-in-a-javascript-object) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript) but, while educational, they aren't dealing with an array *and* an object.  i **do** have underscore in this project, but, again, haven't found anything that i comprehend as useful in this scenario.

how do i get this to run in a way that gives me what i need?

Comment: Assuming we fix the syntax of `dataObject` so it's a proper array storing proper objects: `const results = checkArray.map(val => dataObject.findIndex(o => o.id == val));`

Comment: I just copy/paste from   `var_dump` and tweak, bud. Sufficient to communicate the idea. At any rate,  I'll give your suggestion a whirl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning the indexes, isn't it easier to return the objects themselves?

```js
const matchedObjects = dataObject.filter(
   ({ id }) => checkArray.includes(id)
);
```

That will return all objects having `id` found in your `checkArray`.

Having these objects in `matchedObjects`, you can iterate through them and do whatever you wish.

Comment: uh...yeah... that's so damn obvious, I want to bash my head into the desk... 

Comment: Do it gently 

Comment: lmao. thank you.  this worked perfectly.  more perfectly than i knew i needed, actually.

Answer (score 1):

something like that ?

```js
const checkArray = ['18A38', '182B92', '85F33'] 

const dataOject =
  [ { id:'853K83', isGo:false }
  , { id:'85F33',  isGo:true  }
  , { id:'97T223', isGo:true  }
  , { id:'18A38',  isGo:false }
  , { id:'182B92', isGo:true  }
  ];

const result = checkArray.map(val=>dataOject.findIndex(el=>el.id===val) )


console.log( JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: thank you.  this is excellent.  and it targets exactly the thing i was looking for.

Comment: Weird. I did actually. Here, I clicked again. You do deserve the vote.