# How to return the array of intersection between two array with Lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am trying to return the array of all the intersected array elements.

I got 2 arrays.

The array from api and the filter condition array.

Array from api is this

```
let somethingList = [
      {
        id: 'PROD108',
        name: 'Headsweats Mid Cap',
        CustomFields: [
          {
            name: 'Brand',
            value: 'Headsweats',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eco',
            value: 'False',
          },
          {
            name: 'Test',
            value: '0',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 'PROD109',
        name: 'Performance Liberty City Cycling Cap',
        CustomFields: [
          {
            name: 'Brand',
            value: 'Performance',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eco',
            value: 'False',
          },
          {
            name: 'Test',
            value: '0',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 'PROD110',
        name: 'Castelli Logo Bandana',
        CustomFields: [
          {
            name: 'Brand',
            value: 'Castelli',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eco',
            value: 'False',
          },
          {
            name: 'Test',
            value: '0',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 'PROD159',
        name: 'Performance Classic Sleeveless Jersey',
        CustomFields: [
          {
            name: 'Eco',
            value: 'False',
          },
          {
            name: 'Color',
            value: '#4CAF50',
          },
          {
            name: 'Test',
            value: '0',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 'PROD160',
        name: 'Schwinn Evolution IC Sleeveless Jersey',
        CustomFields: [
          {
            name: 'Brand',
            value: 'Schwinn',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eco',
            value: 'False',
          },
          {
            name: 'Color',
            value: '#2196F3',
          },
          {
            name: 'Test',
            value: '0',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 'PROD161',
        name: 'Performance Elite Short',
        CustomFields: [
          {
            name: 'Brand',
            value: 'Performance',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eco',
            value: 'False',
          },
          {
            name: 'Color',
            value: '#000000',
          },
          {
            name: 'Test',
            value: '0',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 'PROD162',
        name: 'Andiamo! Padded Cycling Brief',
        CustomFields: [
          {
            name: 'Eco',
            value: 'False',
          },
          {
            name: 'Color',
            value: '#808080',
          },
          {
            name: 'Test',
            value: '0',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 'PROD163',
        name: 'Fox Mojave Glove',
        CustomFields: [
          {
            name: 'Brand',
            value: 'Fox',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eco',
            value: 'False',
          },
          {
            name: 'Color',
            value: '#000000',
          },
          {
            name: 'Test',
            value: '0',
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
```

filter condition array.

```
 let testingFilter = ['Fox', 'Performance'];
```

What I want to do is if the `customfield value` of `array from api` is intersected with `testingFilter` value

I want to push them into an array and return that new array.

But the code I written don't return an new array, What should I do to return a new array

```
let filteredProduct = [];
    filteredProduct = _.filter(somethingList, (product) => {
      if (testingFilter.length === 0) {
        return somethingList;
      } else {
        // Here is the problem
        return _.intersection(testingFilter, _.map(product.CustomFields, 'value'));
      }
    });
```

Expected Answer array

```
filteredProduct = [
{
        id: 'PROD109',
        name: 'Performance Liberty City Cycling Cap',
        CustomFields: [
          {
            name: 'Brand',
            value: 'Performance',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eco',
            value: 'False',
          },
          {
            name: 'Test',
            value: '0',
          },
        ],
      },
{
        id: 'PROD161',
        name: 'Performance Elite Short',
        CustomFields: [
          {
            name: 'Brand',
            value: 'Performance',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eco',
            value: 'False',
          },
          {
            name: 'Color',
            value: '#000000',
          },
          {
            name: 'Test',
            value: '0',
          },
        ],
      },
         {
            id: 'PROD163',
            name: 'Fox Mojave Glove',
            CustomFields: [
              {
                name: 'Brand',
                value: 'Fox',
              },
              {
                name: 'Eco',
                value: 'False',
              },
              {
                name: 'Color',
                value: '#000000',
              },
              {
                name: 'Test',
                value: '0',
              },
            ],
          },
]
```

Comment: Can you show an example of an expected answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line taken from your code:

```
_.map(product.CustomFields, 'value')
```

Here, you get an array of all the `values`'s of the `CustomFields`, if we check [if there is an item from `testinFilter` present in that array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312528/check-if-an-array-contains-any-element-of-another-array-in-javascript), we can use that as the `_filter` `return` statement like so:

```js
let filteredProduct = [];
filteredProduct = _.filter(somethingList, (product) => {
    const allCustomFields = _.map(product.CustomFields, 'value');
    return allCustomFields.some(r => testingFilter.indexOf(r) >= 0);
});

// We could rewrite the same code as a one-liner without the extra const like so:
let filteredProduct = _.filter(somethingList, (product) => _.map(product.CustomFields, 'value').some(r => testingFilter.indexOf(r) >= 0));
```

---

**Snippet**:

```js
let testingFilter = ['Fox', 'Performance'];
let somethingList = [{id: 'PROD108', name: 'Headsweats Mid Cap', CustomFields: [{name: 'Brand', value: 'Headsweats', }, {name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, {name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, {id: 'PROD109', name: 'Performance Liberty City Cycling Cap', CustomFields: [{name: 'Brand', value: 'Performance', }, {name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, {name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, {id: 'PROD110', name: 'Castelli Logo Bandana', CustomFields: [{name: 'Brand', value: 'Castelli', }, {name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, {name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, {id: 'PROD159', name: 'Performance Classic Sleeveless Jersey', CustomFields: [{name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, {name: 'Color', value: '#4CAF50', }, {name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, {id: 'PROD160', name: 'Schwinn Evolution IC Sleeveless Jersey', CustomFields: [{name: 'Brand', value: 'Schwinn', }, {name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, {name: 'Color', value: '#2196F3', }, {name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, {id: 'PROD161', name: 'Performance Elite Short', CustomFields: [{name: 'Brand', value: 'Performance', }, {name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, {name: 'Color', value: '#000000', }, {name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, {id: 'PROD162', name: 'Andiamo! Padded Cycling Brief', CustomFields: [{name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, {name: 'Color', value: '#808080', }, {name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, {id: 'PROD163', name: 'Fox Mojave Glove', CustomFields: [{name: 'Brand', value: 'Fox', }, {name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, {name: 'Color', value: '#000000', }, {name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, ];

let filteredProduct = _.filter(somethingList, (product) => {
    const allCustomFields = _.map(product.CustomFields, 'value');
    return allCustomFields.some(r => testingFilter.indexOf(r) >= 0);
});
console.log(filteredProduct);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Result:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "PROD109",
    "name": "Performance Liberty City Cycling Cap",
    "CustomFields": [
      {
        "name": "Brand",
        "value": "Performance"
      },
      {
        "name": "Eco",
        "value": "False"
      },
      {
        "name": "Test",
        "value": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "PROD161",
    "name": "Performance Elite Short",
    "CustomFields": [
      {
        "name": "Brand",
        "value": "Performance"
      },
      {
        "name": "Eco",
        "value": "False"
      },
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "value": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "name": "Test",
        "value": "0"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "PROD163",
    "name": "Fox Mojave Glove",
    "CustomFields": [
      {
        "name": "Brand",
        "value": "Fox"
      },
      {
        "name": "Eco",
        "value": "False"
      },
      {
        "name": "Color",
        "value": "#000000"
      },
      {
        "name": "Test",
        "value": "0"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
let somethingList = [ { id: 'PROD108', name: 'Headsweats Mid Cap', CustomFields: [ { name: 'Brand', value: 'Headsweats', }, { name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, { name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, { id: 'PROD109', name: 'Performance Liberty City Cycling Cap', CustomFields: [ { name: 'Brand', value: 'Performance', }, { name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, { name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, { id: 'PROD110', name: 'Castelli Logo Bandana', CustomFields: [ { name: 'Brand', value: 'Castelli', }, { name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, { name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, { id: 'PROD159', name: 'Performance Classic Sleeveless Jersey', CustomFields: [ { name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, { name: 'Color', value: '#4CAF50', }, { name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, { id: 'PROD160', name: 'Schwinn Evolution IC Sleeveless Jersey', CustomFields: [ { name: 'Brand', value: 'Schwinn', }, { name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, { name: 'Color', value: '#2196F3', }, { name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, { id: 'PROD161', name: 'Performance Elite Short', CustomFields: [ { name: 'Brand', value: 'Performance', }, { name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, { name: 'Color', value: '#000000', }, { name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, { id: 'PROD162', name: 'Andiamo! Padded Cycling Brief', CustomFields: [ { name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, { name: 'Color', value: '#808080', }, { name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, { id: 'PROD163', name: 'Fox Mojave Glove', CustomFields: [ { name: 'Brand', value: 'Fox', }, { name: 'Eco', value: 'False', }, { name: 'Color', value: '#000000', }, { name: 'Test', value: '0', }, ], }, ];
let testingFilter = ['Fox', 'Performance'];

let filteredProducts = somethingList.filter(p =>
    Array.from(p.CustomFields.values()) // iterable to array
        .map(({value}) => value) 
        .some(value => testingFilter.includes(value))) 

console.log(filteredProducts)
```